# How to use rankx by multiple columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have below data, each USIM has its respective Shipped_Qty.
I want to calculate the rank of Shipped Qty by dynamic user filter on: PLM_season, Sourcing_Category, Division.

I have created the following calculated column:

```
rank =
RANKX ( 
    ALLSELECTED ( Test[Shipped_Qty] ), 
    Test[Shipped_Qty],, DESC, DENSE 
)
```

and have below result,

| PLM_Season | Sourcing_Category | Division | USIM | Shipped_Qty | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spring | T-shirt | Men | 200001 | 1000 | 1 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200002 | 900 | 2 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200003 | 800 | 3 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200004 | 700 | 4 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200005 | 600 | 5 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200006 | 500 | 6 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200007 | 400 | 7 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200008 | 300 | 8 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200009 | 300 | 9 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200010 | 200 | 10 |

What I expect would be, if user has selected all PLM_season, Sourcing_Category, Division as his crieteria,

| PLM_Season | Sourcing_Category | Division | USIM | Shipped_Qty | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spring | T-shirt | Men | 200001 | 1000 | 1 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200002 | 900 | 1 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200003 | 800 | 2 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200004 | 700 | 1 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200005 | 600 | 2 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200006 | 500 | 3 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200007 | 400 | 1 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200008 | 300 | 2 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200009 | 300 | 1 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200010 | 200 | 2 |

And also below, if user has selected only PLM_season as his criteria,

| PLM_Season | Sourcing_Category | Division | USIM | Shipped_Qty | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spring | T-shirt | Men | 200001 | 1000 | 1 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200002 | 900 | 2 |
| Spring | T-shirt | Kids | 200003 | 800 | 3 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200004 | 700 | 4 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200005 | 600 | 5 |
| Spring | Pant | Kids | 200006 | 500 | 6 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200007 | 400 | 1 |
| Summer | T-shirt | Kids | 200008 | 300 | 2 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200009 | 300 | 3 |
| Summer | Pant | Men | 200010 | 200 | 4 |

The filter will be placed on a Power BI Dashboard. And I would like the rank calculation to be dynamic on the back-end. Is this possible?

Comment: Calculated Columns don't respond to slicers. For that you'd need a measure.

Comment: But in the end I would actually like to have the 'rank' on the x-axis of a line chart, and Shipped_Qty as y-axis. And a measure could not be put in x-axis...

Comment: i agree with Jos that you can only use measure. measure can be dynamic with slicers and column can be added into x-axis. you can choose either of them but cannot both.

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure = sum(Test[Shipped_Qty])
rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Test,Test[PLM_Season],Test[Sourcing_Category],Test[Division]), [Measure],,DESC,Dense)

rank2 = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Test,Test[PLM_Season]), [Measure],,DESC,Dense)
```

[image]